# Регистрация расширения файла(ассоциация) в Windows для скомпилированного python-файла?

Tags: python, tkinter, файловая-система, компилятор, ос

[Это может как-то помочь?](https://revolution.allbest.ru/programming/00548515_0.html)

Как создать свое расширения для файла, как у `word - (.docx...)`, `rar archiver - (.rar...)`, `Python - (py, pyd, pyc, pyw...)` и т.д. Используя: `Python`, `Tkinter` и компилятор `cx_freeze`. Чтоб, при открытии файла открывалась (exe)программа, создавалось окно `root = Tk()`, и был создан на окне `txt = Text()`, а в `txt` было записано все что находится в файле с расширением:`.qip` - который мы открыли, как такое сделать?

---

Набросок:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text

text = '''Здесь должен/а быть метод/функция который/ая будет читать/возвращать текст в файле который мы открыли: text.qip'''
root = Tk()

txt = Text()
txt.pack()
txt.insert(0.1, text)

root.mainloop()
```